# Predict (un)employment variables - very small dataset

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics

I'm new to econometrics (familiar with ML, Python, Data Visualization). I really have no clear idea what model should I use in order to predict (un)employment variables for 2015-2016 (potentially 2020, but I don't see it doable here). The table is presented below (variable's figures "xxx" are integers):

[image]

Maybe sklearn regression can help me predict figures for 2015, but how those can be used for 2016?

I saw a few posts regarding "panel data" and "Fama-MacBeth Analysis". Pandas has built "Fama-MacBeth" method. If that's the regression method I should use, I would appreciate shedding some light.

Otherwise, can someone refer me to another post (if there is duplicate, sorry about that; I didn't know how to write the question or search properly) or provide me with any kind of help?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Zona

Comment: Do you have a group of firms/regions/etc. that you are trying to forecast or just a single one?

Comment: Just a single one, unfortunately... This is all I have. Thanks.

Comment: Then I am removing the panel data tag.

Answer (score 0):

Forecasting macroeconomic variables with a small sample can be handled using vector autoregression (VAR) which generalizes the autoregressive model to vectors. The advantage is that it will take into considerations the linear interdependencies between the six time-series that you have at hands.

Denote $Y_t$ the 6x1 vector containing your macroeconomic variables. You can estimate the model

$Y_t = \rho Y_{t-1} + e_t$

using [statsmodels in Python](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html), and then predict the future values of the vector. I will advise you to read a bit on the limitations of VAR for forecasting before engaging in this exciting adventure. You can find extensive information in [Vector Autoregressive Models for Multivariate Time Series](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-32348-0_11) for instance. Also, consider first-differencing the vector series since it is probably not stationary.

Good luck!